# Laravel creando creando storage del proyecto con un ln -s del desde otro dir

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

tengo el `storage` de mi **proyecto-x** de laravel  en el directorio `/var/laravel_storages/proyecto-x`.

Entonces lo que he hecho es un `sudo ln -s /var/laravel_storages/proyecto-x/* /var/www/html/proyecto-x/storage/app/public/` . El enlace se crea sin problemas, de hecho accedo desde el proyecto laravel al enlace simbolico y **me muestra su contenido** , pero en la app no.  Despues hago un `php artisan storage:link` para que lo lleve al directorio publico de la app.

Pero no muesta en la app las imagenes cuando debe...

El directorio `/var/laravel_storages` le he puesto el grupo `www-data` por si a caso, pero ni aun asi...

Comment: Deberías elaborar mejor la pregunta. Deberías especificar si tienes la configuración por defecto y además explicar a qué situación te refieres cuando dices "proyecto" y "app"